# Improve performance for accessing large array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, performance, optimization

I'm trying to calculate number of unique entries in a (n x n) multiplication table.
(12x12) Multiplication Table:

```
×   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
2   2   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18  20  22  24
3   3   6   9   12  15  18  21  24  27  30  33  36
4   4   8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48
5   5   10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60
6   6   12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60  66  72
7   7   14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70  77  84
8   8   16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80  88  96
9   9   18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90  99  108
10  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 110 120
11  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99  110 121 132
12  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108 120 132 144
```

Now, nth element of the 'ans' array holds number of unique entries in a (n x n) multiplication table.
 I noticed that it is taking much time to access elements of the large 'mark' array. Though it doesn't take much time if I access a single element every time.
 Now my code takes about 12-13 seconds to finish building up the 'ans' array. Can I optimize it more so that it would take about 5 seconds?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 30000

char mark[(MAX*MAX) + 1];
int ans[MAX+1];

void calc(){
    int i, j, cnt = 0, x;
    ans[0] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            x = i*j;

            if (!mark[x]){
                mark[x] =  1;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        ans[i] = cnt;
    }

}

int main(){
    calc();
    printf("ans[%d] = %d\n", MAX, ans[MAX]);

    /*
    int n, t;
    scanf("%d", &t);

    while (t--){

        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("%d\n", ans[n]);
    }
    */
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I'm trying to calculate number of unique entries in a (n x n) table. Building the table is not the main goal here. I'm using the 'mark' array to check if the new number is unique. I can't think of any other way to do it without the array. I tried using vector bits, it helps to bring down the memory but takes more time. The real slow part of the code is accessing the array elements. There is a big stride each time for n = 30k. without the memory access part-

```
        if (!mark[x]){
            mark[x] =  1;
            cnt++;
        }
```

It takes about only 1 second to finish the program. But I can't think of any way to change the access pattern.
If I was only trying to figure out unique entries in a (30k x 30k) table, I could change the access pattern like this-

```
1 
2   4
3   6   9
4   8   12  16
5   10  15  20  25
```

Currently, we check every row from start to end (left to right)
We can approach every column (top to bottom)

```
int lim = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++){
    lim += MAX;
    for (j = i*i; j <= lim; j+= i){
        if (!mark[j]){
            mark[j] = 1;
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    //ans[i] = cnt;
}
ans[MAX] = cnt;
```

So that, the stride in accessing memory gets less. And the code finishes in about 9 seconds (~3 seconds less) in my PC. But I'm trying to get answers for every (n x n) table.

Comment: a 12x12 multiplication table isnt something that is worth to store in memory at all. Just calculate the entries on the fly as you print them.... ups misread, but  if it is say 1million x 1 million then even more cpu wins over memory

Comment: Have you tried building with optimizations?

Comment: The slow part of this program is the printf() ... as @tobi303 said, it's not worth the memory.  The extra cycle to do the calculation will, for a million x milllion, cost you 1000 seconds; but save you 8000 Gbytes of ram (longs would be required, not just ints).  Even if you can store a fraction of this the RAM cost isn't worth it

Comment: @UKMonkey I don't see how you reach the conclusion that this snippet requires 8000 gigabytes.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you're right - i read tobis reply and missed the OP's 30,000   so it's 4(int) * 30,000 * 30,000 = 14G ... still more RAM than I'd be willing to invest in a multiplication table

Comment: I'm calculating "the number" of unique entries in a (n x n).
now it takes 800 MB of ram... But printf is not making trouble... I am building the array so that i can answer a query in O(1).

Comment: C indexes run from 0! You should rewrite your loops: `for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {...`. Your current code does accesses past end of the array and invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: From memory point of view, `std::bitset<(MAX*MAX) + 1> mark` can replace your `char mark[(MAX*MAX) + 1]`.

Comment: What is the goal here?  If you're looking for unique entries in a multiplication table, brute force is the wrong approach.

Comment: Guys, please do not downvote. There might be better algorithm (which is not that trivial), but the question is legit: how to optimize the existing code.

Comment: @MashrurMahmood we better use just `printf("ans[%d] = %d\n", MAX, ans[MAX]);` in `main()` instead of those scanf/printfs...

Comment: Yes thanks, but MAX is a constant. I am building the 'ans' array so I can answer for any n.

Comment: @MashrurMahmood It is not an optimization suggestion, it is just for the guys who tries to run your example. It is better just to print the answer, rather than waiting for an input...

Comment: Oh, thanks, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution based on bit marks (i.e. we use a bit index as a mark). It reduces the memory footprint by 8 times and about 1/4 faster than the original solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 45000UL

unsigned char bit_mark[(MAX*MAX) >> 3]; // 8 bits per byte
unsigned int ans[MAX + 1];
unsigned char mask_tbl[] = {
    0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80
};

void bit_calc()
{
    unsigned int i, j, cnt = 0, x;
    ans[0] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            x = i * j;
            unsigned int idx = x >> 3;
            unsigned char mask = mask_tbl[x & 0x7];
            if (!(bit_mark[idx] & mask)) {
                bit_mark[idx] |= mask;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        ans[i] = cnt;
    }

}

int main(){
    bit_calc();

    printf("ans[%ld] = %d\n", MAX, ans[MAX]);

    return 0;
}
```

The brute force counting will not scale, a better algorithm would help. Unfortunately, I am not even sure if there is such an algorithm...

Comment: There is one further micro-optimization you can make now, and that's to test multiple bits at once. The data will often be sparse so you can potentially avoid having to check each bit individually by masking multiple bits at once or using FFS instructions on, say, 64-bits at once: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set

Answer (score 0):

Though the compile might have been clever enough to do it on its own, you could try a branchless construct in the innermost loop:

```
int b= !mark[x];
mark[x]|= b;
cnt+= b;
```

Comment: I tried it and the performance is a bit worse that the original solution...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy: yep, I am not surprised, as a write is performed every time. What can the values in `mark` be ?

Comment: those are just flags to count unique numbers. If the mark is not set, we just set it and increase the counter of unique numbers... So we might try to use bits instead, but I am not sure it will help much...

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy: are you really willing to optimize this function, or can other approaches to count the unique entries do ? And do you need all ans[i] ?

Answer (score 0):

To generate this (probably huge and likely pointless) table, you don't need to use multiplication at all.

The first row is just multiplication by 1, so you don't need to actually multiply for that.

For the second row you can add the values in the first row to themselves.

For the third row, you can add the values from the first row to the values from the second row.

For the fourth row, you can add the values from the first row to the values from the third row.

For row N, you can add the values from the first row to the values from row N-1.

The next step would be to use SIMD (e.g. MMX, SSE, AVX) to do 4 (or 8 or 16 or whatever) additions in a single instruction.

The step after that might be to use multiple CPUs/threads (although I'd suspect this won't help much as writes will probably be the bottleneck, not CPU time).

*Note: I'm saying that the table is "probably huge and likely pointless" because it's too large to fit in a CPU's caches, and (for most CPUs) a cache miss is slower than integer multiplication.*

Comment: It is not about multiplication table. There is none in the code. The table in the question was just for the explanation. The bottleneck not the CPU, so I guess the SIMD will not help here...